# Debugging: to System.out.println() or to not System.out.println()

Tags: java, debugging

That is my question. More specifically, I'm trying to get used to Eclipse's debugger and I'd like to know if printing to console is still done in some cases or if it's considered a bad practise that should be entirely avoided. Also, what can be considered as good approach(es) to debugging overall?

Comment: If it's overkill to use a logging library, at the very least write a debug message routine that calls System.[err|out].println().  That way, you can later comment out the println() in one place to tidy things up.  Going through and removing printlns() later on is always a pain.

Comment: It really depends on the specific case. There are cases where `System.out.println()` is actually the better choice than a debugger. You might also be interested in DoodleDebug: http://scg.unibe.ch/wiki/projects/DoodleDebug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best choice would be a logging library (of course, this adds an extra dependency to your project). Check out commons-logging, for instance.
The main advantage is that you can write your debug messages in the DEBUG level and when you deploy your code, you'll just configure the logger to skip those messages (instead of searching for all occurrences of System.out.println in your code).
One other great advantage is that loggers usually can be configured to write anywhere (even send email messages or SMS) also without touching your code.

Comment: In terms of logging library to use, I'd strongly recommend using SLF4J.  It provides an easy to use facade around the actual logging library you're using, making it easier to switch which one you're using.  It's also increasingly being used by libraries, so you may need to grab an implementation for it either way.

Answer (score 13):

Use `System.err.println()` instead.

Why?

`System.out.println()` is often redirected to a file or another output, while this is pretty much always printed on the console. It's easier for debugging and also the right way to do it.

---

Edit (warning: subjective):

Since you asked about whether `System.out.println` should be entirely avoided: I don't believe in *anything* that you must **always** avoid, be it using goto's, crashing your computer with a BSOD, or whatever. Sometimes you just need a quick-and-dirty way to get small things done fast, and it just plain **isn't worth** the 1 hour you'll spend on it to try to do things the "right" way, instead of a 5-minute fix, no matter how good the "good" way is. Use your judgment when deciding if something should be used or not, but never set rules for yourself like "I'll *never* use goto!". :)

Edit 2 (example):

Let's say you're debugging a crashing driver and you suspect that an `if` statement that shouldn't be execute is being executed. Instead of spending three hours finding out how to use `ZwRaiseHardError` to display a message box, just call `KeBugCheck` inside the `if` and crash the darned system. Sure, you'll reboot, but unless your reboot takes hours, you just saved yourself that much time.

Comment: I like the insight your edit offers. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: -1 for spending 5 minutes to write a hack instead of 1 hours to write it correctly and save 6 hours of debugging later.

Comment: @Falmarri: If it takes me more than 10 minutes to debug a 5-minute piece of code, I just switch to the right way, not spend 6 hours fixing it. But I'd also feel *very* sorry for you if you spent 1 hour figuring out how to display errors the "right" way, if you could just do a `println` and quit in 30 seconds, and get your job done in 5 minutes. (I'd complain about the -1, but then again, this *is* opinion, so feel free to disagree.) :)

Comment: Takes one hour now -- but by the time you need to go to do it the right way, it may very well take you six hours -- and that might be the best case scenario -- just depends on how many other developers have built crappy hacks on top of it that the entire system now depends on. -- Not to mention, some other poor bastard that does want to do things the right way can't now, because your hack prevents it and has to spend an hour of his time figuring out a compatible hack that doesn't suck... -- Man... I'll never understand Java developers.

Answer (score 3):

1. Minor point: if your program actually outputs something useful to the console via System.out, you may want to instead print the debugging info to `System.err`
2. You should generally strive to have as much debugging as possible (ideally using some standard logger like `log4j`). This both eases debugging when you're actually developing the program AND allows for much easier debugging of already-released code in production. The benefit is that your code remains unchanged and you don't need to ADD debugf prints, yet by default the logging config can turn off the logging until it's actually needed (or at least turn down the level of logs)
3. As far as general simple "throw `println`s at the wall" debugging, it can sometimes be one of the fastest ways to debug, though it should by no means be the only/main one.

   Why can it be useful? Among other reasons, because running a Java program in a debugger may be much slower than outside of it; or because your bug manifests in an environment/situation that can't be easily replicated in your Eclipse debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If the debugging print lines are not going to stay in the code after you've fixed your bug, then do whatever is easiest for you.  Lambert's advice of using System.err.println() is a good idea since you can differentiate it from other output that your program may produce.  If the debugging print lines are going to stay in your code, then I would advise on using a logging framework like log4j.  This way you can dial up or down the level of output based on whether you're trying to debug something or just running in production.  Be sure to output things at the right level when using log4j.  Don't just log everything at INFO.

Answer (score 0):

I use `System.out.println` for my debugging in case i have a problem or to inform me that methods have started to make sure everything has worked properly but when I publish the program I always remove it because it slows down the program.